# Single Link List Addition - Infinite Loop

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am writing a simple link list addition code.
If i am adding the same node again... i am getting infinite loop issue.

The code is as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _linklist
{
    int             iNodeId;
    struct _linklist    *pNextNode;
}LINKLIST;

void printNode(LINKLIST **pNode)
{
    LINKLIST *pCurNode = *pNode;
    while(NULL != pCurNode)
    {
        printf("pCurNode->iNodeId   %d\n", pCurNode->iNodeId);
        pCurNode = pCurNode->pNextNode;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void AddNode(LINKLIST **pNode, LINKLIST *pNewNode)
{
    LINKLIST *pHead = *pNode;
    if (NULL == pHead)
    {
        *pNode = pNewNode;
    }
    else
    {
        while(NULL != pHead->pNextNode)
        {
            pHead = pHead->pNextNode;
        }
        pHead->pNextNode = pNewNode;
    }
}

void main()
{
    int iNodeCnt = 0;
    LINKLIST *pNode1;
    LINKLIST *pNode2;
    LINKLIST *pNode3;

    LINKLIST **pNode = (LINKLIST **)malloc(sizeof(LINKLIST *)); // Double pointer to hold the link list.
    *pNode = NULL;

    pNode1 = (LINKLIST *)malloc(sizeof(LINKLIST));
    pNode1->iNodeId = ++iNodeCnt;
    pNode1->pNextNode = NULL;

    pNode2 = (LINKLIST *)malloc(sizeof(LINKLIST));
    pNode2->iNodeId = ++iNodeCnt;
    pNode2->pNextNode = NULL;

    pNode3 = (LINKLIST *)malloc(sizeof(LINKLIST));
    pNode3->iNodeId = ++iNodeCnt;
    pNode3->pNextNode = NULL;

    AddNode(pNode, pNode1);
    AddNode(pNode, pNode2);
    AddNode(pNode, pNode3);

    printNode(pNode);

    AddNode(pNode, pNode1);

    printNode(pNode); // goes into infinite loop. ????

    getchar();
}
```

Hope the code is understandable.

Here, the second printNode() goes into infinite loop.

Is there any problem with AddNode() ?

Thanks Olaf, ooga and Iman...
Working code after Modification:

```
LINKLIST *pNode4;

AddNode(pNode, pNode1);
AddNode(pNode, pNode2);
AddNode(pNode, pNode3);
printNode(pNode);

// Copy the Node1 to Node4 and then call AddNode()
pNode4 = (LINKLIST *)malloc(sizeof(LINKLIST));
pNode4->iNodeId = pNode1->iNodeId;
pNode4->pNextNode = NULL; // Set the pNextNode to NULL

AddNode(pNode, pNode4);

printNode(pNode);

getchar();
```

Comment: Can you include some of the `printf` output in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put the *exact same node* into two places in the list. If you want another copy of a node's data then make a copy (ensuring `pNextNode` is `NULL`) and add that.

Answer (score 3):

`AddNode` appends the new node at the end of the list. Before you append `pNode1`, you already have

```
pNode1 -> pNode2 -> pNode3 -> NULL
```

Now you add `pNode1` to the end of the list and get

```
pNode1 -> pNode2 -> pNode3 -> pNode1 -+
            A                         |
            +-------------------------+
```

This is causing the endless loop, when you traverse the list in `printNode`

Answer (score 1):

The reason you go to infinite loop is because of that your link list is ininite ! 
[image]

when you enter to print function it goes to link list 
1-print node 1 
2-then look at next node is node 2
3-print node 2
4-then look at next node is node 3
5- print node 3
6- then then look at next node is node 1
goes to 1 and so on...